# How to run script on different context to the current window?

Tags: javascript, eval, sandbox

Code:

```
var dataScript = '$("#foo").append("$ and #foo exists!")';
```

Suppose we have some library loaded (ex: $jQuery) in our document, if we run this

```
eval(dataScript); //This will work and adds a text to our current document
```

I want:

```
eval(dataScript); //$ is undefined (Maybe you're in another context?)
```

I currently use JSJS library http://jterrace.github.io/js.js/ but this library is necessary to manually add many essential items such i.e `window`, `document`, `etc ...`

There will be some method to run script without interacting with the current page?. **There should also be communications between the current window and the new context.**

+

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Be carefull the question mention "this library is necessary to manually add many essential items such i.e window, document, etc ..."  but WebWorker as well can't directly manipulate a DOM entity

Comment: ES6 does not provide any new APIs for this, so I don't see how it is related to your question

Comment: Paul S with "WebWorkers" can not use document, window and DOM manipulation

Answer (score 1):

You can use Iframe with the sandbox option, that's the best solution to me
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp